# Multiple actions were found with WebAPI post - WHY isn't this working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api

I've spent the whole day on this, I'm pretty much bald now.

Controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddSet(SetDto set)

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("copy")]
public HttpResponseMessage CopySet([FromUri]int[] ids)
```

Routes in order:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });


        routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Set",
           routeTemplate: "api/set/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "set", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I call `copy` with `POST /api/set/copt/ids`, and `add` with `POST /api/set`.  What am I doing wrong?

Full error:

> "exceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the
>   request: \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
>   AddSet(App.Repository.Models.Dtos.SetDto) on type
>   App.Service.Controllers.SetController\r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
>
> CopySet(Int32[]) on type App.Service.Controllers.SetController",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are getting the above error when making a request like `POST /api/set/copt/ids` ?

Web API is strict about matching route variable names to the action parameter names.

Try doing the following and see(*note*: the Name parameter in FromUri would map the route variable name to your parameter here...this is called aliasing):

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("copy")]
public HttpResponseMessage CopySet([FromUri(Name="id")]int[] ids)
```

Answer (score -2):

In your routetemplate you only allow api/set/{id}. But none of your request follow that pattern.

Comment: I also allow "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", and I do very clearly have a request that follows the pattern: POST /api/set